# How to convert grilled Beer Can Burger recipe to oven baked

Tags: baking, grilling, hamburgers, beer

I've been looking at Beer Can Burger recipes where you make a big burger and push a beer can in it to make a hole and then fill the whole with veggies, cheese etc and wrap bacon around the burger.  The instructions say to grill on indirect heat for 1 hour.  How long and at what temp would I make these at in the oven?  Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the oven at a lower to warm setting like 200 to 250 Fahrenheit (93 to 121 Celsius) is a good approximation for long, slow indirect cooking on a grill.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you like your burgers.  If you want any sort of browning or crispyness on the outside (which I would recommend), you will need to cook them at at least about 300 °F (150 °C) for the [Maillard Reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) to occur.  But that poses a problem if you also want the burger to be cooked rarer than well-done (which I also recommend, especially if you are grinding the meat yourself).  The trouble is that, assuming you put the veggies in raw, they will need a long time to cook.

Here is what I would do if I were you:

1. Pre-cook the bacon in a frying pan
2. Remove the backon and form into a ring in the desired size of the burger
3. Cook the veggies by themselves in a frying pan in the bacon drippings until the desired texture is reached
4. Remove the veggies and mix in the cheese
5. Form the burgers inside the bacon rings with the cooked veggies in the middle
6. Salt the burgers at the last minute
7. Fry the burgers on high heat back in the skillet for a couple minutes per side, or until the desired doneness is achieved

If you don't care about delicious browning and crispyness, and are content with more of a meatloaf-like texture, mix the ground meat with salt, form the "burgers" entirely raw, and bake at a very low temperature (~200 °F) for an hour or more.

If you don't want to dirty your skillet but still want browning, you could try roasting the burgers at ~350 °F or even higher, but then you seriously risk completely overcooking the beef by the time the veggies have cooked.